# Remove appstats from web.xml (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine

it seems ridicolous, but I am unable to remove appstats. 
If I remove the following from the web.xml:

---

```
 <filter> 
        <filter-name>appstats</filter-name> 
        <filter- 
class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter</filter- 
class> 
        <init-param> 
            <param-name>logMessage</param-name> 
            <param-value>Appstats available: /appstats/details? 
time={ID}</param-value> 
        </init-param> 
    </filter> 
    <filter-mapping> 
        <filter-name>appstats</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>
```

---

my static content is not accessible any more and produces a 404 error. 
I narrowed it down to the filter and filter-mapping tags, since I 
removed the other tags from 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html 
step by step. 
Only if those specific tags remain in the web.xml, the static content 
becomes inaccessible after deployment. 
Last night I had strange errors in the logs which are linked to source 
files of appstats. 
Hopefully you guys can help me.

Greets
upscale

Answer (score 0):

Did you also delete the servlet definition :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also, if you included it, you should clean up your appengine-web.xml :

```
<admin-console>
    <page name="Appstats" url="/appstats" />
</admin-console>
```

Comment: Yes I did. It turned out that I could resolve it changing the static-setting:  `<static-files>
        <include path="/content/*" expiration="0d 0h 0m 0s" />
    </static-files>`had to be changed in the appengine-web-xml to  `<static-files>
        <include path="/content/**" expiration="0d 0h 0m 0s" />
    </static-files>` Strange enough, since there does not seem to be any connection.